# SAS Proc SQL, combine where, left join and case

Tags: sas

I have three piece of code. How can I combine them into one so that they look elegant? data1: pull data with some condition; data2: data1 left join new data; data3: set to data2 and create a new variable.

```
proc sql; create table data1 as select
a.ID,
b.decison_CD,
c.type,

from
dataA  a,
dataB  b,
dataC  c,

where a.ID=b.ID
and   a.ID=c.ID
and   c.type not in ('Unknown')
and   b.decison_CD in (‘Y’,’N’)
; quit;


proc sql;
create table data2 as select 
a.*
,b.payId

from data1 a
left join datanew b
on a.ID=b.ID;
quit;

data data3;
set data2;
if payID= . then booked =0;
else if payID=1 then booked=1;
run;
```

Comment: If the code works, and you're just looking to refactor it, you might get more help at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you can just use left joins and treat datanew as a fourth dataset:

```
proc sql;
    create table data1 as select
        a.ID, b.decison_CD, c.type, d.payId,
        case when missing(d.payId) then 0 else
            case when d.payID = 1 then 1 end end as booked
        from dataA as a
        left join dataB (where = (decision_CD in('Y','N'))) as b on a.id = b.id
        left join dataC (where = (type notin('Unknown'))) as c on a.id = c.id
        left join datanew as d on a.id = d.id;
quit;
```

Comment: One more question, if I have two conditions, should I use where = and(A and B)?

Comment: You don't need the first and - just try "left join dataX (where = (two = 2 and six = 6 and CD ~= "DVD" and ...))"

Comment: And works. if I want to add    month = substr(compress(vvalue(RECEIVEDT),'/'),1,2);
   year = substr(compress(vvalue(RECEIVEDT),'/'),3,4);
   YR_MNTH_CD= cats(of year month)*1; Use case when? or a.date as newdate format =?????. The main idea is I want to conver time format to numeric YYYYMM.

Comment: The latter - x.date as newdate format [date format]. Also, if this answered your question, please mark it as such with the little check mark on the left.